# Use batch file to replace (C*) in csv file

Tags: csv, batch-file

I have a csv file with 18 fields. The fourth field includes several sub-strings I'd like to remove including (C: 1-0-1), (NET), and (MR). The following does not work if the sub-string includes parentheses. How can I make this batch file remove any sub-string with a wildcard (C*)? I have used "rem" to help troubleshoot, but the final batch file needs to remove (C*), (NET) and (MR) from the fourth field.

```
1,"MAY090178","D ","BATMAN HUSH COMPLETE TP (C: 1-1-0)",24.99,11.2455,11.25,3,7,         ,62464962,"76194127923700111","1401223176","978140122317552499","                    ",0,"DC COMICS",000000
1,"NOV141747","F ","BLACK BUTLER GN VOL 19 (C: 1-1-0)",13.00,7.5400,7.54,3,7,         ,62464962,"","0316259403","978031625940851300","                    ",0,"YEN PRESS",127143
2,"MAY151682","F ","BLACK BUTLER GN VOL 20 (C: 1-1-0)",13.00,7.5400,15.08,3,7,         ,62464962,"","0316305014","978031630501351300","                    ",0,"YEN PRESS",127143
1,"AUG180208","D ","BULLY WARS #2 CVR A CONLEY",3.99,1.7955,1.80,1,7,         ,62464962,"70985302666200211","","","                    ",0,"IMAGE COMICS",140749
1,"OCT180162","D ","BULLY WARS #4 CVR A CONLEY",3.99,1.7955,1.80,1,7,         ,62464962,"70985302666200411","","","                    ",0,"IMAGE COMICS",140749
10,"SUPPLY123","J ","COMICARE LONG COMIC BOX (SOLD IN 10) (NET)",2.53,2.5330,25.33,12,7,         ,62464962,"603259601235","","","                    ",0,"",000000
```

---

```
rem | Remove (C: 1-1-0) etc from titles
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=¶" %%A in ('"type     datatest_update.csv"') do (
    SET string=%%A
rem SET string2=%%A
rem SET string3=%%A
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    SET modified=!string:(C: 1-1-0) = !
rem SET modified2=!string:EXTRAS (NET) = !
rem SET modified3=!string:(MR) = !

    >> datatest_update_2.csv echo(!modified!
    endlocal
)
```

EDIT: I have updated the file to the following but it does not run. Should I be using delims=, instead of delims=¶ ?

```
rem | Remove (C: 1-1-0) etc from titles
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=¶" %%A in ('"type datatest_update_6.csv"') do (
    SET string=%%A
    SET modified=!string: (C: 1-1-0)=!
    SET modified=!modified: (NET)=!
    SET modified=!modified: (MR)=!
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    >> datatest_update_7.csv echo(!modified!
    endlocal
)
```

Comment: well, you try to replace `(C: 1-1-0)<space>` with `<space>`, but there is no space in your file at that position. Use `SET modified=!string: (C: 1-1-0)=!`, followed by `SET modified=!modified: (NET)=!` and `SET modified=!modified: (MR)=!`.

Comment: We meet again lol... Let me just clear something, so all lines with `C: 1-1-0` or `C: *` you want removed?

Comment: @JohnKens not the lines, just the strings within the lines.

Comment: Yes, I need to delete the sub-strings, not the lines. I am researching the findstr /v command which might fit my needs.

Comment: no, `findstr` just looks for the string, but returns the full line. Not helpful here.

Comment: Why are you using `type`? Can't you just use the filename?

Comment: "Should I be using `delims=,`?" No. Use `"delims="` (without `tokens`) to read the complete line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a basic Replace function. The first thing we need to do is search for the data that contains `(C: 1-1-0)` EX: `"BATMAN HUSH COMPLETE TP (C: 1-1-0)"`. From here we can set this as the `"Replace this"` within the line. The `"search this"` string will be the entire `Raw` Line data.

Since your data is within the fourth column, we can use `delims=,` to help gather this data. After we find this data inside the `loop` we can call the replace function using the `CALL` command. The Replace function will only edit the line it needs so other untouched data will remain.

```
@ECHO OFF
@setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

Set "InputFile=File.csv"
Set "FindText=(C: 1-1-0)"

Rem | Expand Document To Loop
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('Type "%InputFile%"') do (

    Set "OriginalLine=%%A"
    Rem | Only Find The Parses Containing "(C:"
    for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4* delims=," %%B in ('Echo %%A^| find /I "%FindText%"') do (

        Rem | Remove The Proper String
        SET "RemoveMe=%%E"
        CALL :EditLine !RemoveMe!

    )
)

GOTO :EOF

:EditLine
REM | Change The %RemoveMe% To ""
Set ReplaceText=!OriginalLine:%1=""%!

REM | Make sure we only edit the ListOfItems line.
FOR /F "delims=" %%n IN ('findstr /n "^" %InputFile%') DO (
    SET line=%%n
    SET Modified=!line:%OriginalLine%=%ReplaceText%!
    SET Modified=!Modified:*:=!

    REM | Output the entire edited INI to a temporary file.
    >> %InputFile%.TEMP ECHO(!Modified!
)

Rem | Delete Original File, Restore New
DEL %InputFile%
REN %InputFile%.TEMP %InputFile%

GOTO :EOF
```

---

**EDIT:**

Based on a misunderstand, I though you wanted to completely remove the entire contents of the column containing `(C: 1-0-1)`. The script will fix this and the "Wildcard" issue.

As far as I know, the `find` command has no expandable wildcards in batch. If I am wrong about this someone please correct me in the comments.

However, to overcome this problem we can simply find lines in the document containing `(C:` then in the replace function remove the last 11 characters of the 4th column's string. Using the find statement you can also limit your results down to example: `(C: 1-0` instead of `(C:` - This will not touch any lines with ex: `(C: 1-2`, in the file but all `1-0-*` will be changed.

```
@ECHO OFF
@setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

Set "InputFile=File.csv"
Set "FindText=(C:"

Rem | Expand Document To Loop
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('Type "%InputFile%"') do (

    Set "OriginalLine=%%A"
    Rem | Only Find The Parses Containing "(C:"
    for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4* delims=," %%B in ('Echo %%A^| find /I "%FindText%"') do (

        Rem | Remove The Proper String
        SET "RemoveMe=%%E"
        CALL :EditLine !RemoveMe!

    )
)

GOTO :EOF

:EditLine
REM | Remove The %FindText% To Restore Later
REM | Since the find command has no wild cards we will remove it via "~0,-11%"
REM | This will remove the last 11 characters in the string
Set SaveMe=!RemoveMe:"=%!
Set "SaveMe=%SaveMe:~0,-11%"

REM | Change The %RemoveMe% To %SaveMe%
Set ReplaceText=!OriginalLine:%1="%SaveMe%"%!

REM | Make sure we only edit the ListOfItems line.
FOR /F "delims=" %%n IN ('findstr /n "^" %InputFile%') DO (
    SET line=%%n
    SET Modified=!line:%OriginalLine%=%ReplaceText%%!
    SET Modified=!Modified:*:=!

    REM | Output the entire edited INI to a temporary file.
    >> %InputFile%.TEMP ECHO(!Modified!
)

Rem | Delete Original File, Restore New
DEL %InputFile%
REN %InputFile%.TEMP %InputFile%

GOTO :EOF
```

**Variation #2 - Choose Strings to EDIT:**

In this version I will provide the ability to select the individual lines to edit by allowing multiple search strings. This will also work with "Wildcards"..

Example: The `Call :FindText "(C: 1-1-0)" "(C: 1-1-2)" "(C: 1-2"` function will remove the following from the fourth column's in the document.

- `(C: 1-1-0)` - Removes from existing column.
- `(C: 1-1-2)` - Removes from existing column.
- `(C: 1-2` - Remove **ALL** `1-2-*` from existing column's.

**BatchScript:**

```
@ECHO OFF
@setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

Rem | Configuration
Rem | To use the command, Call :FindText "Desired Text One" "Desired Text Two" "exc..."
Set "InputFile=File.csv"
Call :FindText "(C: 1-1-0)" "(C: 1-1-2)" "(C: 1-1-3)"

pause
GOTO :EOF

Rem | Loop Through Each Search Results
:FindText
for %%A in (%*) do (

    Rem | Expand Document To Loop
    for /f "tokens=*" %%B in ('Type "%InputFile%"') do (

        Set "OriginalLine=%%B"
        Rem | Only Find The Parses Containing "(C:"
        for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4* delims=," %%C in ('Echo %%B^| find /I %%A') do (

            Rem | Remove The Proper String
            SET "RemoveMe=%%F"
            CALL :EditLine !RemoveMe!

        )
    )
)

GOTO :EOF

:EditLine
REM | Remove The %FindText% To Restore Later
REM | Since the find command has no wild cards we will remove it via "~0,-11%"
REM | This will remove the last 11 characters in the string
Set SaveMe=!RemoveMe:"=%!
Set "SaveMe=%SaveMe:~0,-11%"

REM | Change The %RemoveMe% To %SaveMe%
Set ReplaceText=!OriginalLine:%1="%SaveMe%"%!

REM | Make sure we only edit the ListOfItems line.
FOR /F "delims=" %%n IN ('findstr /n "^" %InputFile%') DO (
    SET line=%%n
    SET Modified=!line:%OriginalLine%=%ReplaceText%%!
    SET Modified=!Modified:*:=!

    REM | Output the entire edited INI to a temporary file.
    >> %InputFile%.TEMP ECHO(!Modified!
)

Rem | Delete Original File, Restore New
DEL %InputFile%
REN %InputFile%.TEMP %InputFile%

GOTO :EOF
```

---

For help on any of the commands do the following:

- `call /?`
- `set /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `find /?`
- So on.